# Touch/Increase Laravel Redis Throttle

Tags: laravel, redis, throttling

Im using the Redis Throttle from Laravel for some API communications as the example:

```
Redis::throttle('key')
                ->block(0)->allow(100)->every(5)
                ->then(function () use ($job, $next) {    
                 // do stuff
                }, function () use ($job) {
                   $job->release(5);
                });
    }
```

But in other parts of the system (which are not being fully refactored right now) I need to touch the throttle (mark that I used it) without really blocking the calls.

How can I do it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is stored on redis database as a hash.  If my key is named "key" it is stored on app_name_database_key and has the following format

```
redis:6379> HGETALL app_name_database_key

1) "start"
2) "1592994588"
3) "end"
4) "1592994688"
5) "count"
6) "12"
```

So it is accessible by the Redis Facade without need to tweak the prefix.

```
>>> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::hget('key', 'count');
=> "10"
```

The same can be done to increment it

```
>>> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::hincrby('key', 'count', 1);
=> 11
```